# Document Readability

Tags: python, nlp

What are the ways to determine the level of difficulty w.r.t. the complexity of concept for any given document ?

I am aware of Flesch Reading Ease Score, but that's generic and based on word count and syllables count.

Is there anything that works at the concept level ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please define "concept level"